# How to (intermittently) skip certain cells when running IPython notebook?

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook, ipython-magic

I usually have to rerun (most parts of) a notebook when reopen it, in order to get access to previously defined variables and go on working.

However, sometimes I'd like to skip some of the cells, which have no influence to subsequent cells (e.g., they might comprise a branch of analysis that is finished) and could take very long time to run. These cells can be scattered throughout the notebook, so that something like "Run All Below" won't help much.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Ideally, those cells could be tagged with some special flags, so that they could be "Run" manually, but would be skipped when "Run All".

**EDIT**

`%%cache` (ipycache extension) as suggested by @Jakob solves the problem to some extent.

Actually, I don't even need to load any variables (which can be large but unnecessary for following cells) when re-run, only the stored output matters as analyzing results.

As a work-around, put `%%cache folder/unique_identifier` to the beginning of the cell. The code will be executed only once and no variables will be loaded when re-run unless you delete the unique_identifier file.

<del>**Unfortunately**, all the output results are lost when re-run with `%%cache`...</del>

**EDIT II** (Oct 14, 2013)

The master version of ipython+ipycache now pickles (and re-displays) the codecell output as well.

For rich display outputs including Latex, HTML(pandas DataFrame output), remember to use IPython's display() method, e.g., `display(Latex(r'$\alpha_1$'))`

Comment: If you don't need to redisplay the output, you can define your own skip magic like I did here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43584169/4098821

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Currently, there is no such feature included in the IPython notebook.
Nevertheless, there are some possibilities to make your life easier, like:

- use the `%store` or maybe better the `%%cache` magic (extension) to store the results of these intermittently cells, so they don't have to be recomputed (see https://github.com/rossant/ipycache)
- add a `if==0:` before the cells you don't want to execute
- convert these cells to raw cells (but you will loose the already stored output!)

(see discussion at https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/2125)

Comment: Great to know about ipycache extension, which functions similarly to what I'm doing (manually) now, but only better! The `%%cache` magic effectively serves as the special flag when "Run All", and manual re-run requires simply cache file deletion. Brilliant! Thanks, Jakob~

Comment: Indeed using %%cache is much more convenient than manually handling with %store. %store need to send one by one the variables to save, but can read all at time, little pointless. %%cache works perfect for whole cell, and %store works better for single variables.

Comment: `ipycache` is no longer maintained- do you know any other solutions?

Comment: @Chris_Rands currently I use the freeze extension. You might ask Rossant directly.

Answer (score 75):

Though this isn't exactly what you seem to be looking for, if you wish to entirely omit the execution of a cell (where no cached results are loaded), you can add the following hack at the beginning of a cell (assuming you are using a Unix-based OS):

```
%%script false
```

or a variant (working as of early 2020 -- see [here](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/whatsnew/version7.html#id18) for explanation):

```
%%script false --no-raise-error
```

As noted in comments, the shorter

```
%%script true
```

also works, though maybe not on all platforms.

Comment: Anyone know how to do this on Windows?

Comment: It works perfectly on windows. The notebook output will be "Couldn't find program: 'false'".

Comment: This stopped working some time in 2019. You can find new workarounds [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59806154/9201239).

Comment: As a heads up, this gets rid of existing output. Not useful if you want to keep previous output of the cell.

Comment: Here's another similar one (`%%script echo`): https://stackoverflow.com/a/61544643/1090455

Comment: instead use this as it works on all known platforms:

%%script echo skipping

Comment: What about `%%script true` instead of `%%script false --no-raise-error`?

Comment: I would put the option first to show that it belongs to the `%%script` magic, not the `false` command: `%%script --no-raise-error false` --- @wjandrea `%%script true` will probably fail on some non-POSIX platforms like Windows. Also the falsy return status could be probably used as an explicit indication that the cell did not (correctly) execute?

Answer (score 26):

Here's a simple and universal solution without the need for workarounds:
Simply type this as the top line of the cell to skip the cell:

```
%%script echo skipping
```

On all platforms it will proceed without executing the code in the cell.

On Mac and Unix-like platforms it simply prints "skipping" as cell output to indicate that it has been skipped.  On Windows it displays an error message instead (something like command echo not found), unless you happen to have installed something that provides an echo command such as cygwin, gnuwin32, bash, or git, but this error message is ignored and harmless.

Alternatively, I guess converting the cell to a raw cell (as in accepted answer) works too although it may no longer format the contents properly as code, now displaying it is raw text.

Some of the other proposed solutions are more platform-specific.

Comment: Works in Hydrogen on Ubuntu

Comment: Works much better than `%% false` as it doesn't create an error. This is very good if you don't need to keep old output.

Comment: Actually it turns out this works but does normally create an (ignored) error on Windows unless you have an echo command in your path (e.g. from installing cygwin, gnuwin32, bash, etc.)

Comment: Works beautifully on Google Colab too...

Comment: Also works with Dataiku.

Answer (score 12):

If no cached results are expected to be loaded, I find the `Freeze` nbextension quite useful to this end.

[image]

Although unofficial, I strongly recommend to give these notebook extensions a try if you have never used them before.

To install the extension machinery,

```
$ pip install jupyter_contrib_nbextensions && jupyter contrib nbextension install
```

To enable the `Freeze` extension, launch `jupyter notebook` and open a new notebook, from the menu select `Edit` > `nbextensions config`, and then check `Freeze`.

Comment: Looks like the best solution. When hitting "Restart and Run All" or other commands, the frozen cells won't be re-executed but the cell outputs are still there.

Comment: This is the best solution. The cell won't run, even you press run and the output will still be there.

Answer (score 2):

This question is a bit older, but the most convenient answer seems to be missing. You can use the 'initialization cells' from the NBextensions. Once installed/activated, you can in any notebook mark cells as 'initialization cells' which can then be run with a specific button.

- Install NBextensions:[here](https://jupyter-contrib-nbextensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html)
- Activate 'initialization cells' when you launch the jupyter dashboard
- In your notebook, in the 'view' menu choose 'cell toolbar' then 'initialization cell'
- Next to each cell there is now a checkbox. Mark all the cells you want to run for initialization
- When reopening a notebook, click the button that looks like a pocket calculator to run all the initialization cells.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to skip python code in jupyter notebook cell from running, I temporarily convert those cells to markdown.

Comment: but in this way you lose the output

Comment: why someone needs output for the code he/she doesn't want to run?

Comment: In data science you don't want to run the whole notebook every time, but still you want to be able to see the results

Answer (score 1):

The `%%script false` solution stopped working some time in 2019.

Here are some other available workarounds. These are based on programs ignoring their arguments when you tell them not to expect any. Here are some easy examples:

Perl:

```
%%perl -e0
​
for i in range(10): print(i)
```

Here you're running: `perl -e '0' cellcontents`

A more memorable version:

```
%%perl -eat
​
for i in range(10): print(i)
```

Here you're running: `perl -e 'at' cellcontents`

Bash:

```
%%bash -c :

for i in range(10): print(i)
```

`:` is a no-op in bash, so you're running: `bash -c : cellcontents`

I haven't looked at the external magic  implementation code, but I'm pretty sure "cellcontents" are passed as arguments and won't be interpreted by shell by mistake, say if you were to include `;` in them and accidentally inject some bad code. But I can't guarantee you that.

I'm sure you can come up with other creative solutions, by looking at the supported programs here: https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#cell-magics

Comment: %%script false --no-raise-error
works for the purpose on the Jupyter I tried today

Comment: indeed, it does, but it's a way too long to type and remember... Ideally, ipython should have a `%%script noop` or something similar, so it's a feature and not a workaround.

Comment: Why such complicated solutions. There is a POSIX command which always returns true. You can use: `%%script true`

Answer (score 1):

Simplest solution: **just add `%` character as first(new) line of the cell** and entire cell's content will be skipped.

**Cons:**

- A single line error message will be shown under the cell:

  > UsageError: Line magic function `%` not found.

**Pros:**

- The error message is very short and therefore doesn’t impair the notebook legibility.
- It's the quickest on/off solution for specific cells.

Answer (score 0):

For the cells you wish to skip when you press `Run All` you can use `try`/`except` blocks, where you try to display the already calculated information in the `try` block, and perform the calculation in the `except` block.

Take this cell for example:

```py
my_results = 2 # Assume this is a bigger calculation
print(my_results)
print('displayed my results.')
```

To skip the calculation for this cell in subsequent runs, change the contents of this cell to the following:

```py
try:
  print(my_results)
  print('displayed state value')
except:
  my_results = 2 # Assume this is a bigger calculation
  print(my_results)
  print('displayed newly calculated value')
```

The first time you run this cell, it will attempt to print the value of the state variable `my_results`. This throws an exception so it jumps to the `except` block and does the actual calculation of `my_results` (which in this case just makes it equate to `2`). At the end of the first run the output for this cell would be:

```
2
displayed newly calculated value
```

When you run the cell a second time (whether that be manually or via `Run All`), the `try` block will first execute but this time since the variable is available in the state, it does not throw an exception. Instead it displays the result and the `except` block is never run. At the end of the second run the output of this cell would be:

```
2
displayed state value
```

This doesn't meet your explicit criteria that the cell should be completely skipped, but effectively the calculation is skipped.

If the displaying of the information is more complex than using a single `print` or `display`, it would probably be cleaner if you make the displaying routine into a function like so:

```py
def print_my_results(my_result):
  print(my_result)
  print('displayed my result.')

try:
  print_my_results(my_results)
except:
  my_results = 2 # Assume this is a bigger calculation
  print_my_results(my_results)
```

Comment: this is clever, but can you achieve the same thing with a simple if...else block?

Comment: Good observation @MattMontag, I had to think about it for a little bit but I would say this try/catch is better than an if/else block: With an if/else you need to track and account for every used variable in the if statement. There can be a situation where you forget to update that if statement. With a try/catch you don't need to worry about that. You can just focus on printing the variable and if you forget a calculation it will throw another exception in the `except` block prompting you to add the missing calculation upstream or in the `except` block.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround I sometimes use:

```
if 0:
    time_consuming_function()
```