# Export individual cell in IPython/Jupyter notebook

Tags: export, ipython, cell, jupyter

I am able to export the entire notebook as HTML, but I would like to export just a single cell, together with its output.

Is there some way of doing this?

Comment: I have same question: is there a way to export a selected subset of IPython cells, for example to create a summary HTML report?

Comment: See related discussion and options at [Hide input cells · Issue #534 · jupyter/notebook](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/534)

Comment: Also, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26494747/simple-way-to-choose-which-cells-to-run-in-ipython-notebook-during-run-all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do this is to use a custom preprocessor.

I explain how to do this briefly in response to [Simple way to choose which cells to run in ipython notebook during run all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26494747/simple-way-to-choose-which-cells-to-run-in-ipython-notebook-during-run-all).

To summarize: you can extend `nbconvert.preprocessors.ExecutePreprocessor` to create a preprocessor that checks cell metadata to determine whether that cell should be executed and/or output.

I use Jupyter Notebooks for report generation all the time, so I wrote a collection of custom processors to extend nbconvert behavior:

- meta-language to determine what cells get executed and included in the final report (if/else logic on entire notebook sections)
- executing code in markdown cells
- removing code cells from output.
- taking input arguments from the command line

I haven't had time to wrap these in an distributable extension, but you can see the code here: https://gist.github.com/brazilbean/3ebb31324f6dad212817b3663c7a0219.

Please feel free to use/modify/do-great-things with these examples. :)