# Selectively import from another Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, data-science

I arranged my Jupyter notebooks into: `data.ipynb`, `methods.ipynb` and `results.ipynb`. How can I selectively import cells from *data* and *methods* notebooks for use in the *results* notebook?

I know of `nbimporter` and `ipynb` but neither of those offers selective import of variables. There is an option to import definitions - including variables that are uppercase - but this does not work for me as I would have to convert most of the variables in my notebooks to uppercase.

I would rather import everything except for two or three cells that take a long time to evaluate. Ideally, I would like to defer the execution of some assignments to the very moment I access them (lazy evaluation) - but I understand that it might be difficult to implement.

Here is the overview, in pseudocode (each line repesents a cell):

`data.ipynb`:

```
raw_data = load_data()
dataset = munge(raw_data)
describe(dataset)             # I want this line to be skipped at import
```

`methods.ipynb`:

```
import data
method = lambda x: x * x
# showcase how the method works on a subset of the dataset
method(data.dataset[:5])      # I want this line to be skipped at import
```

`results.ipynb`:

```
import data
import methods
result = methods.method(data.dataset)
describe(result)
```

The motivation is that my real *data* and *methods* notebooks:

- are way much longer and complicated, hence I want to use an import system
- there are only a couple of cells that take more than seconds to evaluate

also, the *methods* notebook cannot be replaced with `methods.py` file. In fact, I have such a file which contains the implementation details of my method. The notebook is more of a place to specify default parameters, showcase how my method works and explain example results.

This question is essentially a combination of:

- [How can I import from another ipython-notebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19564625/how-can-i-import-from-another-ipython-notebook), and
- [Simple way to choose which cells to run in ipython notebook during run all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26494747/simple-way-to-choose-which-cells-to-run-in-ipython-notebook-during-run-all)

I read through answers to both and none satisfied my requirements.

In my answer below I present my solution that uses custom cell magics and monkey-patching. However, I would prefer a solution which allows specifying which cells/expressions to exclude/include not in the notebook of origin (e.g. `data.ipynb`) but in the target one (e.g. in `methods.ipynb`).

For example, it could use regular expressions:

```
# all variables starting with 'result' would be ignored
nbimporter.options['exclude'] = '^result.*'
```

or (even better) lazy evaluation:

```
# only `a` and `b` would be evaluated and imported
from data import a, b
```

All ideas will be appreciated!

Answer (score 6):

So far I've been monkey-patching `nbimporter` and selecting cells to exclude using cell magic:

```
from IPython.core import magic

@magic.register_cell_magic
def skip_on_import(args, cell):
    get_ipython().ex(cell)
```

The code used to monkey-patch of cell remover:

```
import ast

class SkippingTransformer(ast.NodeTransformer):
    # usage:
    # import nbimporter 
    # nbimporter.CellDeleter = SkippingTransformer

    def visit(self, node):
        if (
            isinstance(node, ast.Expr)
            and isinstance(node.value, ast.Call)
            and isinstance(node.value.func, ast.Attribute)
            and node.value.func.attr == 'run_cell_magic'
            and node.value.args[0].s == 'skip_on_import'
        ):
            return
        return node
```

And an actual example, `data.ipynb`:

[image: data.ipynb]

And `methods.ipynb` (the exception at the end is intended - it means success!):

[image: methods.ipynb]

**Edit**: I published the above code as a part of [jupyter-helpers](https://github.com/krassowski/jupyter-helpers) some time ago. Using this package one simply needs to import the importer in the importing notebook:

```
from jupyter_helpers.selective_import import notebooks_importer
```

and the cell-magic can be imported in the imported notebook with:

```
from jupyter_helpers.selective_import import skip_on_import
```

Here is example imported notebook: [Data.ipynb](https://github.com/krassowski/jupyter-helpers/blob/master/demos/Data.ipynb) and example importing notebook: [Results.ipynb](https://github.com/krassowski/jupyter-helpers/blob/master/demos/Results.ipynb)