# Ipython Notebook: Elegant way of turning off part of cells?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

In my `ipython notebook`, there is part of cells that serves as preliminary inspection.

Now I want to `turn it off`, since after running it I know the status of the dataset, but I also want to keep it, so other people using this notebook can have this functionality.

How can I do it? Is there any example of doing it?

1. I can `comment out` these cells, but then switching between `on` and `off` would be quite laborious. And may not be quite convinent for other people.
2. I can abstract it into a `function`, but that itself has some methods, so the code would be quite convoluted, and may be hard to read?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to (intermittently) skip certain cells when running IPython notebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19309287/how-to-intermittently-skip-certain-cells-when-running-ipython-notebook)

Comment: Adding - any way to do it while saving the previous output?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Using Jupyter notebook you can click on a cell, press `esc` and then `r`. That converts it to a "raw" cell. Similar thing can be done to convert it back, `esc` + `y`. No comments needed, just key presses.

Within Jupyer notebook, go to Help -> Keyboard shortcuts for more.

Here's a snippet:

> Command Mode (press `Esc` to enable)
>
> - ↩  : enter edit mode
> - ⇧↩  : run cell, select below
> - ⌃↩  : run cell
> - ⌥↩  : run cell, insert below
> - y  : to code
> - m  : to markdown
> - r  : to raw

Comment: Teach your friends about the trick, or add a comment in the NB explaining your method, so others could do the same.

Comment: Wow, this is very intersting, nerver heard of it. But how can I `esc+r` for several `consecutive cells`? The code I want to turn off invovles several cells, not a singel one.

Comment: Best I got is merge the cells, and then esc+r.

Comment: Addtionally, I tried to abstract all the cells into functions, and the trigger then by a seris of function. This can work, but make the code hard to maintain now, since the `function` and `result` are seperated in different cells.

Comment: That is super cool. Are the raw cells outputted when you convert the notebook to pdf or HTML?

Comment: Figure it worth mentioning: For people that don't like keyboard shortcuts, you can also just click on the block, then use the "type" dropdown in the toolbar to switch it to "raw": https://i.imgur.com/R0Ef4W5.png

Comment: thank you @Venryx I don't always like keyboard shortcuts and thought I was alone on that

Answer (score 52):

In Jupyter notebooks one can use this magic preamble at the beginning of a cell to avoid its execution:

```
%%script false --no-raise-error
```

Comment: With this solution you get to keep the syntax highlighting, which is nice.

Comment: I tried this and got output: "Couldn't find program: 'false'" . Still useful, though, so thanks @Davide Fiocco

Comment: Worked beautifully also in google Colab

Comment: I found it not so elegant since the cell seems to hang forever

Comment: can you do it for the whole section ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a condition at the cost of one extra indentation.

```
cellEnabled = 0
#cellEnabled = 1

if cellEnabled:
    doA()
    doB()
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same kind of desire and I eventually found out about the nbextension called Freeze. When you enable it, you get a nice freeze button in your toolbar. When you click it, the cell you're currently in will become "frozen". This means it will turn green (making it visually clear) and it will be ignored by the Run All process. It's also locked for editing, so you do need to unfreeze it (unlock button, two over to the left of the freeze button) before editing or running the cell. That's really easy to do though because it's just one button.

Let me know if this wasn't super clear. Otherwise, I hope this helps!

Comment: Does it keep the cell output as well? a screenshot could be nice

Comment: If the cell had been run previously, that output will stick around and stay the same. I don't seem to be able to put screenshots in comments though.