# Jupyter notebook: how to leave one cell out while 'run all'

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I'm writing python using jupyter notebook and I have two cells that can influence each other.

I'm wondering is it possible to leave some certain cells out after I click `Restart & Run All` so that I can test the two cells independently?

Answer (score 3):

One option based on Davide Fiocco's answer of this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34192290/ipython-notebook-elegant-way-of-turning-off-part-of-cells) and that I just tested is to include `%%script` magic command on each cell you don't want to execute.
For example

```py
%%script false --no-raise-error
for i in range(100000000000000):
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 3):

I recently discovered an easy way to do this.

You may have noticed that cells can be set as type Code or Markdown - this lets you prepare the notebook with headers and explanatory text (in Markdown), but also sections of executable code (the default).  This can be set from a drop-down already on the screen if using via Jupyter Lab.  In Jupyter Notebook I think it's under the Cells menu.
You can also use keyboard shortcuts (first hit Escape if needed to get out of text-entry mode: <kbd>Y</kbd> for Code, <kbd>M</kbd>for Markdown, or <kbd>R</kbd>for Raw.

Wait, what's that about Raw?  It appears to just take away the code highlighting and make the cell not executable!  So <kbd>Esc</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to make it Raw, then execute like you wanted to, then <kbd>Esc</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> if you want to re-enable that block.

Alternative:  If you want a quicker way to comment out all the lines but leave it as a Code block, make sure you are in edit mode (click on the cell contents), do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> (for select-all), and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>  (for "comment this line").  I tested with python and it inserts # at the beginning of each selected line.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to create a parameter and run the cells accordingly

```
x = 1

# cell 1
if x == 1:
    // run this cell

# cell 2
if x != 1:
    // run the other cell
```

In this example, you will skip `cell 2`.

Answer (score 1):

If you put those two cells at the end of the page, you can run all cells above a certain cell with a single click.

That or you can put a triple-quote at the beginning and end of the two cells, then un-quote the cells to test them.