# Disable Jupyter Notebook cell only for whole notebook run

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I don't know if it is possible, but I have a Jupyter notebook where I'd like to disable some cells in case of a whole run.
That is, 'Run All' would jump over these cells and not trigger them, but they could still be used if ran alone (e.g. with Ctrl+Enter) without changing the code.

I know `%%script false --no-raise-error` does the trick, but you need to manually change a constant to re-enable the cells when you need them. Ideally, I'd not have to change anything in the code.

Comment: It's simply done.  I do it all the time.  In large Notebooks I tend to have different parts of the notebook segregated and grouped for certain tasks.  And sometimes these different tasks do not depend on another tasks.  Or sometimes the different tasks may not need to run sequentially.    Etc...  So what I do is insert a cell above a group of cells (a task) and then enter a letter or something similar that causes this cell to generate a Jupyter Run error.  All the cells below this error cell stop being Run.  Then I move down below this group of  tasked cells,  and then select Run All Below.

Comment: That's useful, but it's not quite what I want to achieve. Your solution needs the 'separated' cells to be below the others, while ideally they would be scattered in between. I'm looking for a way to jump over a cell, in a way

Comment: There isn't a "go to ... " command in Jupyter that I've heard of.  And haven't used a go-to command in probably more than 20 years since basic.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ipython Notebook: Elegant way of turning off part of cells?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34192290/ipython-notebook-elegant-way-of-turning-off-part-of-cells)

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't. I was looking for a way to do this without the need to change anything, so that I may run any cell individually but exclude some from a `Run all` execution and not have to worry about the cells' states.