# Can't find module cPickle in poetry and jupyter

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pickle, python-poetry, ipycache

I am trying to cache some variables in Jupyter notebook cells that are big and take long to compute. I use Ubuntu 20.04 and Python 3.8. I added `ipycache` in my pyproject.toml file and it was successfully installed with Poetry. Then, I added `%load_ext ipycache` in a cell and when I execute it I get:

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_47459/791109313.py in <module>
----> 1 get_ipython().run_line_magic('load_ext', 'ipycache')

~/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/toxic-comments-bias-kaggle-yMytpa1p-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py in run_line_magic(self, magic_name, line, _stack_depth)
   2362                 kwargs['local_ns'] = self.get_local_scope(stack_depth)
   2363             with self.builtin_trap:
-> 2364                 result = fn(*args, **kwargs)
   2365             return result
   2366 

~/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/toxic-comments-bias-kaggle-yMytpa1p-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/decorator.py in fun(*args, **kw)
    230             if not kwsyntax:
    231                 args, kw = fix(args, kw, sig)
--> 232             return caller(func, *(extras + args), **kw)
    233     fun.__name__ = func.__name__
    234     fun.__doc__ = func.__doc__

~/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/toxic-comments-bias-kaggle-yMytpa1p-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/IPython/core/magic.py in <lambda>(f, *a, **k)
    185     # but it's overkill for just that one bit of state.
    186     def magic_deco(arg):
--> 187         call = lambda f, *a, **k: f(*a, **k)
    188 
    189         if callable(arg):

~/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/toxic-comments-bias-kaggle-yMytpa1p-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/IPython/core/magics/extension.py in load_ext(self, module_str)
     31         if not module_str:
     32             raise UsageError('Missing module name.')
---> 33         res = self.shell.extension_manager.load_extension(module_str)
     34 
     35         if res == 'already loaded':
~/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/toxic-comments-bias-kaggle-yMytpa1p-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/IPython/core/extensions.py in load_extension(self, module_str)
     78             if module_str not in sys.modules:
     79                 with prepended_to_syspath(self.ipython_extension_dir):
---> 80                     mod = import_module(module_str)
     81                     if mod.__file__.startswith(self.ipython_extension_dir):
     82                         print(("Loading extensions from {dir} is deprecated. "

/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py in import_module(name, package)
    125                 break
    126             level += 1
--> 127     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
    128 
    129 

/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/_bootstrap.py in _gcd_import(name, package, level)

/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/_bootstrap.py in _find_and_load(name, import_)

/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/_bootstrap.py in _find_and_load_unlocked(name, import_)

/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/_bootstrap.py in _load_unlocked(spec)

/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/_bootstrap_external.py in exec_module(self, module)

/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/_bootstrap.py in _call_with_frames_removed(f, *args, **kwds)

~/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/toxic-comments-bias-kaggle-yMytpa1p-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ipycache.py in <module>
      9 
     10 # Stdlib
---> 11 import inspect, os, sys, textwrap, cPickle
     12 
     13 # Our own

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cPickle'
```

I thought that `pickle` is used by default in Python >=3, and whenever `cPickle` is imported, then it automatically uses `pickle` instead. However, this import (`import inspect, os, sys, textwrap, cPickle`) is not on my end, so I cannot do something like `import pickle as cPickle` to fix this error. It also seems `ipycache` is not maintained anymore. Is it possible to resolve this issue from my side, or should I try a different caching method?

Answer (score 1):

As of the latest released Pip version (0.1.14), ipycache has not fixed this known bug ([ipycache Github issue](https://github.com/rossant/ipycache/issues/46)). However, there is an apparent plan to release a fix to this in an upcoming release (0.1.5). In the mean time, that ipycache issue gives a solution of using the latest developer version with

```
pip install git+https://github.com/rossant/ipycache --upgrade
```

which I can confirm worked for me as it worked for others commenting on the Github issue.

Answer (score 0):

I also could not get it running in an Azure Databricks environment as of 2022 because of the same `cPickle` import error. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19309287/how-to-intermittently-skip-certain-cells-when-running-ipython-notebook) has alternatives to `ipycache`.

The [Freeze](https://jupyter-contrib-nbextensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/nbextensions/freeze/readme.html) jupyter notebook extension seems to offer the almost the same caching functionality.