# vscode supports python scripts that can be run interactively - is there an option to have a section that runs only in interactive mode?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

vscode supports python scripts that can be run interactively - is there an option to have a section that runs only in interactive mode?

that is, this snippet should be run as a notebook cell in interactive mode, but not when running as script

a possible option would by a flag like the **name** variable - but it appears to be **main** both when running as a script, and when running interactively

this [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19309287/how-to-intermittently-skip-certain-cells-when-running-ipython-notebook) includes some workarounds, but I'm hopping for something cleaner

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to (intermittently) skip certain cells when running IPython notebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19309287/how-to-intermittently-skip-certain-cells-when-running-ipython-notebook)

Comment: it's a workaround, I was hopping for something cleaner

Comment: Are you using jupyter or py files? Can you give specific examples? If there's no way to implement this for now, perhaps a GitHub report would be more appropriate.